# AngularJS material - side nav not working using jade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, material-design, angular-material

I'm currently working on a project using Angular Material. I'm running into an issue where I'm unable to toggle/open the sidenav. I've pasted a portion of the code below. I'm using Jade as the templating engine. In the controller, I'm able to log the ID, which is from the md-component-id attr. Can someone please point me in the correct direction to resolving this issue? Probably a layout issue?

Thanks.

---

main.jade

```
#layout-vertical-navigation(layout='row', flex, style='height:100%;')
        md-sidenav#vertical-navigation.md-sidenav-left.md-whiteframe-z2(ng-include='"/app/layout/partial/left-sidebar.html"', md-component-id="sideNav", md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')")
```

---

left-sidebar.jade

```
div(ng-controller='LeftSidebarController as leftSidebar')
     md-toolbar(layout='row')
        md-button.md-icon-button(ng-click='leftSidebar.openSideNavPanel("sideNav")')
            md-icon.material-icons menu
     md-content
        md-list
            md-list-item(ui-sref='home')
                md-tooltip(md-direction='right') Dashboard
                md-icon.material-icons home
                p Dashboard
```

left-sidebar.js
    ....

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('ignoreme')
    .controller('LeftSidebarController', LeftSidebarController);

LeftSidebarController.$inject = ['$mdSidenav'];

/* @ngInject */
function LeftSidebarController($state, $mdSidenav) {

    function openSideNavPanel(id) {
        console.log(id);
        $mdSidenav(id).toggle();
    }

    /////////////////////////////////
    var vm = this;

    vm.openSideNavPanel = openSideNavPanel;
}
```

})();

Answer (score 0):

main.jade

```
div(ng-include='"/app/layout/partial/left-sidebar.html"')
```

left-sidebar.jade

```
#sideNavContainer(ng-controller='LeftSidebarController as leftSidebar', layout='row')
  md-content
    md-button.md-icon-button(ng-click='leftSidebar.openSideNavPanel("sideNav")')
        md-icon.material-icons menu
  md-sidenav.md-sidenav-left.md-whiteframe-z2(md-component-id='sideNav')
    md-content
        md-button.md-icon-button(ng-click='leftSidebar.openSideNavPanel("sideNav")')
            md-tooltip(md-direction='right') Close Navigation
            md-icon.material-icons keyboard_arrow_left
    md-list
        md-list-item(ui-sref='home')
            md-tooltip(md-direction='right') Dashboard
            md-icon.material-icons home
            p Dashboard
        .....
```